# Insertion and selection sort in PHP

Tags: performance, php, sorting, insertion-sort

I've implemented InsertionSort and SelectionSort in PHP and tested it with an array of 20.000 unique integers.

It took many seconds to complete the insertion selection sorts.  For comparison, I saw a Java implementation that only took 3 seconds for both combined. I wanted to ask if my implementations are just bad or if this is a hardware/language based problem.

Here are my methods:

```
$rand = randomArray(20000);
insertionSort($rand);
selectionSort($rand);


function insertionSort($sort_array){
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sort_array)-1; $i++){
      for ($j = $i + 1; $j > 0; $j--)
        {    
          if($sort_array[$j-1] > $sort_array[$j]){
            $temp = $sort_array[$j-1];
            $sort_array[$j-1] = $sort_array[$j];
            $sort_array[$j] = $temp;               
          }         
        } 
    }
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo $time;
    return $sort_array;
}

function selectionSort($sort_array) 
{
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sort_array) - 1; $i++)
    {
        $min = $i;  
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($sort_array); $j++)
        {
            if ($sort_array[$j] < $sort_array[$min]){
              $min = $j;
        } 
      $temp = $sort_array[$i];
      $sort_array[$i] = $sort_array[$min];
      $sort_array[$min] = $temp;
    }
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo $time;
    return $sort_array;
    }
} 

function randomArray($max){
    $random = range(0, $max-1);
    shuffle($random );
    return  $random;
}
```

Comment: You cannot compare the performance of something written in php, an interpreted, string-based language, with something written in java, a compiled language with machine data types.

Comment: @MikeNakis Well, that's a point. But i never thought this would be so extreme. But, my code looks fine or is still optimizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible inefficiency is that you are copying the array when you call the function.  If you [pass parameters by reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), then you could avoid allocating and copying the array.  See the difference in these two functions that just perform one swap:

```
function f($a) {
    $swap = $a[0];
    $a[0] = $a[1];
    $a[1] = $swap;
    return $a;
}

function g(&$a) {
    $swap = $a[0];
    $a[0] = $a[1];
    $a[1] = $swap;
}

$xyz = array('x', 'y', 'z');
print_r($xyz);                  # array { [0] => x  [1] => y  [2] => z }
$yxz = f($xyz);
print_r($xyz);                  # array { [0] => x  [1] => y  [2] => z }
print_r($yxz);                  # array { [0] => y  [1] => x  [2] => z }
g($xyz);
print_r($xyz);                  # array { [0] => y  [1] => x  [2] => z }
```

---

That aside, there is not that much you can do to optimize your two sorting algorithms.  You could try obtaining the length `count($sort_array)` just once, before the loop, to see if makes any difference.

The important thing to note, though, is that both insertion sort and selection sort are O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithms.  That means that if you double the size of the array, it will take approximately quadruple the amount of time to complete the sort.  **If you care about performance when sorting large lists, you don't use insertion sort or selection sort.**  You pick a more efficient algorithm that tends to work in O(*n* log *n*) time, such as [quicksort](/questions/tagged/quicksort).

Comparing performance across languages is not a very useful way to judge the quality of your code.  To make a comparison that is at least somewhat fair, try racing against PHP's own [`array_sort()`](https://secure.php.net/array_sort) function.

Comment: I initially had the count stored in a variable, after removing this the script became slightly faster. Thanks for your answer, I'd never use this in RL but this was part of an assignment

Comment: Can you take a look at the greaphs on the demo site?: http://techtreedev.de/BA/algorithm/index.php
From left to right: runtime, swaps, comparisons
Are those realistic figures?

Comment: Sure, I see no reason to doubt them.

Comment: Ok, thx, i was a bit suspicious about comparison: insert, as it's in this case n-1